# How to count preceding sibling count until certain condition is fulfilled?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following XML .. I want to get the count of 'step' nodes from current 'step' node to the preceding step which has node event with value 'DoubleClick'.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gps> 
  <step>
    <event>DoubleClick</event>
  </step>    
  <step>
    <event>click</event>
  </step>
  <step>
    <event>click</event>
  </step>  
  <step>
    <event>click</event>
  </step>
  <step>
    <event>DoubleClick</event>
  </step>    
  <step>
    <event>click</event>
  </step>      
  <step>
    <event>click</event>
  </step>
  <step>
    <event>click</event>
  </step>
  <step>
    <event>DoubleClick</event>
  </step>  
</gps>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following xpath when the current node is `step`:

```
count(preceding-sibling::step[generate-id(preceding-sibling::step[event = 'DoubleClick'][1]) = generate-id(current()/preceding-sibling::step[event = 'DoubleClick'][1])])
```

**EDIT:**
And if you want to count even the `step` with *DoubleClick*, use this xpath:

```
count(preceding-sibling::step[event = 'DoubleClick'][1]) * (count(preceding-sibling::step[generate-id(preceding-sibling::step[event = 'DoubleClick'][1]) = generate-id(current()/preceding-sibling::step[event = 'DoubleClick'][1])]) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you could accomplish this, here's one:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/gps">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="step">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="x">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position() - count(preceding-sibling::step[event='DoubleClick'][1]/preceding-sibling::step)" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="event" />
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that while simple to implement, it is a bit CPU-intensive. For a large amount of steps, you may prefer something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="event">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <x>
        <xsl:number from="step[event='DoubleClick']" level="any" />
    </x>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="position() - count(preceding-sibling::step[event='DoubleClick']/preceding-sibling::step)" />                                      this step in your solution resolved my problem thanks

Comment: @JakBalikai If your question is answered, please close it by accepting one of the answers.